# Instantiate javascript class without calling the constructor

Tags: javascript, class

**Short version**

Given the following class:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        throw new Error("No!")
    }

    // ... more functions ...
}
```

How can I get an instance of Foo?

**Explanation**

The class *actually* looks like more this:

```
const KEY = Symbol("BAR")
function validateBarData(input) { 
    /* throws error if input is not in the format: */
    /* {name: "string", bartender: "string", drinks: [ "string" ]} */
}
class Bar {
    constructor(name, bartender, drinks) {
        this[KEY] = {name: name, bartender: bartender, drinks: drinks}
        // now validate to protect against garbage input like
        //   'name = 42' or 'drinks = undefined', etc.
        validateBarData(this[KEY])
    }

    encode() {
        return this[KEY]
    }

    static decode(data) {
        validateBarData(data)
        return new Bar(data.name, data.bartender, data.drinks)
    }

    // ... more functions ...
}
```

`encode()` and `Bar.decode(data)` are used to serialize state to something `JSON.stringify`able so the object can be recreated later. The actual encode/decode logic here may be more complex than just 'dump `this[KEY]`' (e.g. encoding objects managed by the `Bar` object).

Problems when decoding:

- `validateBarData` is called twice
- Although we already have a valid internal state to assign to `this[KEY]` after the first line of `decode`, it first has to be destructured then recreated.

I'd like to avoid this duplication, but I've not been able to find the right way to do it.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1):

Oops.

```
let foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype)
```

or

```
static decode(data) {
    validateBarData(data)
    let bar = Object.create(Bar.prototype)
    bar[KEY] = data
    return bar
}
```

Seconds before posting the question I tried one last thing, and it turns out I should have been calling `Object.create` on the prototype, not the class itself. How embarrassing...

I'm posting anyway because the keywords in the question title weren't showing up in search results (at time of writing; lots about java, but not javascript), so maybe this'll save someone else time in future.